# Ag-grid or our own custom table for filtering and sorting?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid enterprise in my project with angular4 and it is awesome. But I have a requirement where I need to show almost 20 table or more than that, in single html page. So here I am bit concern whether I should use 20 ag-grid instance or shall I create my own custom table with ng-repeat like [this](https://long2know.com/2017/04/angular-custom-table-component-sorting/) which will perform sorting and filtering.

I am looking for below points:

- Which one would be faster? (I think Ag-grid will always be faster in sorting and filtering)
- Which one would be light weight?
- Is it fine if i use 20 ag-grid at one page?
- Data I am handling at a time is nearly(200-300)
- I want only filtering and sorting feature.
- All 20 tables have there different Header and data set some table having 10 or 20 records and some of then having 200-300 records?
- Browser should not take much time to load or It should not break

Or 
Any other suggestion to handle this scenario ?

Comment: You should just try it. I even have a lot of experience with ag-grid and I still don't know the answer without trying it. I feel like it would work fine, but there might be a small delay when initialising the grids at the start (especially on a slower device).

Comment: @thirtydot Yeah I feel like, that's the only option i need to try it. But it is going to take time. I was looking for some expert advice.